# What physical coins of bitcoin exists?

Tags: physical-coins

Whenever a news article is written about bitcoin, it has this "physical" gold/brass coin with detailed circuitry on it as an article picture.

For examples see [here](https://www.insiderfinancial.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Two-Bitcoins.png) and [here](http://cdn.phys.org/newman/gfx/news/hires/2016/howdoyoumine.jpg).

Does this really exists? Who makes them and where can I buy one? Is it from gold? I am specifically interested in the coin with this "detailed circuitry" like the two on the pictures I linked. I was able to find some sellers of physical coins, but they are not as detailed/precise.

What other physical coins "of bitcoin" exist?

Answer (score 1):

Casascius Coins are the ones that have been the most well known, though according to their website they no longer contain any actual bitcoin as of Nov 27, 2013.

https://www.casascius.com/

I am not familiar with any others, though I did find [this article](http://www.coindesk.com/10-physical-bitcoins-good-bad-ugly/) to be informative.

The pictures linked in the question look like they may be the Cryptmint coins in the article.

I also suspect that many of those pictures used in articles are just well-done computer-generated images.