# I collected 5 bitcoins. I have the coins Ross Approved MJS 2013-2018. I do not know if I ever registered a Bitcoin account. How can know?

Tags: physical-coins

How can I sell my Bitcoin collection? I do not know if the coins have been registered.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What physical coins of bitcoin exists?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/49918/what-physical-coins-of-bitcoin-exists) many of these collectibles have no  Bitcoin value associated with them. A few types had Bitcoin value.

Comment: Hello, welcome to bitcoin.stackexchange! Your question doesn't really make much sense to me, what is 'Ross Approved MJS 2013-2018'? Are you talking about some physical coins? Maybe https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/22796/i-am-new-to-bitcoin-how-can-i-get-started can be of help to you?